# Manjaro Update is not possible due to dependecies

Tags: software-installation, updates

Updates are not possible since libkipi needs kxmlgui and also needs service.
How to bypass this or install needed data?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.